# If $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le x^2$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is differentiable at 0.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> If $ f\colon \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le x^2 $ for every $x \in  \mathbb{R} $, then $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

The solution provided uses delta-epsilon to prove this statement. Is there another way to prove this without it?

Comment: There is no other way to do it. The $\epsilon-\delta$ method is just the rigorous way to do it.

Comment: @AhmedHussein Errr... no? Do you use the Peano axioms every time you want to show something about the set of natural numbers?

Comment: @ClementC. that is irrelevant

Comment: No, that's exactly the point. From the definitions, theorems are proven. Composition theorems, etc. Using these theorems (after checking the assumptions apply) to establish other results is as rigorous as can be.

Comment: @ClementC. I am not suggesting that your method is not rigorous. I think I should have said "The $\epsilon-\delta$ method is the formal way to do it" (if that is the correct terminology). What I am saying is that your argument is essentially: when $x$ approaches $0$, the term approaches zero. This is an epsilon-delta argument in a disguise (you just omitted the details for a completely formal argument). My point is that you did not actually suggest a different approach to the problem.

Comment: Again, I disagree with your use of "The." It is *a* formal way to do it. Maybe *the* formal way to do it with the least additional background, if one starts with the $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-definition. But you seem to state that this approach is more formal than any other -- which which I disagree. Unless you are using "formal" here in the sense of "most elementary/closest to the (given) definition," which is not the original meaning of the word.

Comment: @ClementC. is it possible to start with something other than the epsilon-delta definition? Even if it were, I don't see why this should be of any relevance to the point of this discussion, which is how the approach you suggest is considered 'another method to solve the problem'.

Comment: "There is no other way to do it. The $\epsilon-\delta$ method is just the rigorous way to do it." (Quoting your answer verbatim) This stream of comments has nothing to do with my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- First, note that $f(0) = 0$, as $\lvert f(0)\rvert \leq 0^2$ by assumption.
- Then, rewrite, for $x \neq 0$,
  $$
  \left\lvert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right \rvert
  =\left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{x}\right \rvert
  \leq 
  \left\lvert \frac{x^2}{x}\right \rvert = \lvert x\rvert \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} 0
  $$
  which show, by the very definition, that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: beautiful! thank you!